# How to redirect website to particular file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

There is a domain name. Let's say `domain.com`.

When the user types `domain.com` only, he should be redirected to the address `domain.com/file.html`. How can I do that with a `.htaccess` file?

Plus, what does `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` mean? Would it help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex file.html
```

Comment: What about index.php file? If I write index.php file it redirects to the file.html

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Yes, i've tried, it works. Maybe it's hosting's problem? Because it always redirects to domain.com, when you add index.php, even without DirectoryIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site: [.htaccess tricks and tips](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php) It's a good reference for rewrite rules.

As for what does RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] mean.  It's going to ignore anything with an index.php ending [Rewrite Rule meaning](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081205085002AAkibIk)

Comment: I wrote DirectoryIndex file.html, but when index.php is, it also redirects to file.html

Comment: is that the only entry (RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]) in your .htaccess file?

Comment: even if I delete all htaccess code, it still redirects to domain.com, when you type domain.com/index.php and there's nothing in index.php file that redirects it.

Comment: do you have access to the host?  there maybe a redirect setup on the web server.

Comment: is there an httpd.conf file on the server or another rewrite method being used.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect you can make a index page (the first page that the user visits)

```
DirectoryIndex file.html
```

modifying your .htaccess file according to this [link](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?).

For `RewriteRule` you need to able the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module in apache and then make in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) file.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the `RewriteRule` you can put regular expressions to identify the url and redirect the user to a file that you want (in this case you would redirect all your links to `file.html`). More info [here](http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php).

Moreover in the configuration file of the apache server by default is possible you have the next configuration:

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php3 index.cgi index.pl index.html index.htm index.shtml index.phtml
</IfModule>
```

So, by default if you have a file called `index.php` in your webroot of your domain.com always that file would be called first.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following in your .htaccess file located in the root of domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#put all the following rules before any other rules in the .htaccess file
RewriteRule ^file\.html$ - [L]

#domain.com or any subdomain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
#the root of domain   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [NC]
#return file.html
RewriteRule . file.html [L]
```